# $f:A\times B\to\mathbb{R}$ integrable, exists set of measure zero $X\subset A$ so $x\in A-X$, the function $f_x:B\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, continuity

> Let $f:A\times B\to\mathbb{R}$ integrable in the block $A\times
>  B\subset \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$, the cartesian product of the blocks
>   $A\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ and $B\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that there
>   exists a set of measure zero $X\subset A$ such that, for all $x\in
>  A-X$, the function $f_x:B\to\mathbb{R}$, defined by $f_x(y) = f(x,y)$
>   is integrable

My book has this theorem:

> Let $f:A_1\times A_2\to \mathbb{R}$ integrable in the product of
>   blocks $A_1\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ and $A_2\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. For all
>   $x\in A_1$, let $f_x:A_2\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_x(y) = f(x,y)$
>   and let
>
> $$\phi(x) = \underline{\int_{A_2}} f_x(y)\ dy, \ \ \psi(x) =
>  \overline{\int_{A_2}} f_x(y)\ dy$$
>
> The functions $\phi, \psi: A_1\to\mathbb{R}$ are integrable, with
>
> $$\int_{A_1}\phi(x) \ dx = \int_{A_1}\psi(x) \ dx = \int_{A_1\times
>  A_2} f(x,y)\ dxdy$$
>
> that is,
>
> $$\int_{A_1\times A_2} f(x,y) \ dxdy = \int_{A_1}dx
>  \left(\underline{\int_{A_2}}f(x,y)\ dy\right) = \int_{A_1}dx
>  \left(\overline{\int_{A_2}}f(x,y)\ dy\right)$$

This theorem guarantees that when the function on the cartesian is integrable, then the functions in each of the blocks of the product are integrable. So, since $f$ is integrable, we have by the theorem that $f_x(y)$ is integrable in $A_1 = A$, right? Now I have to prove that there exists a portion of this $A$ that has measure $0$, and since $f_x(y)$ is automatically integrable in all of $A$, it'll be in this portion, right? But what's the point of all this? How to prove that such set exists? There are no extra assumptions.

Comment: How I would proceed is to say that the set $X$ is the set of all $x$ such that $f_x$ is not integrable in $B$. Then we set to prove that $X$ has measure zero, because if $X$ has a positive measure then $f$ would not be integrable in $A \times B$.

Comment: For the Lebesgue integral, this is Fubini's theorem. What are the $\overline\int$ and $\underline\int$? Darboux integrals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem does not give you the desired result that $f_x(y)$ is integrable in $A_1=A$. It simply says that $\phi,\psi$ are integrable over $x$.

To prove that $f_x(y)$ is integrable, you need to show that $\phi(x)=\psi(x)$ for almost all $x\in A$. Note that the theorem does not give this. It only says that $\int_A \phi(x) dx =\int_A \psi(x) dx $.

You need $\phi(x)=\psi(x)$ almost everywhere i.e. the set over which they may differ is of measure zero. Such a set can of course be an empty set. For many 'normal' functions, this set over which they differ would indeed be a null set. All you need to show is that the set cannot be of non-zero measure.

In general when two integrals coincide, the integrands generally do not. For example $$\int_0^{2\pi} sin(x) dx = \int_0^{2\pi} cos(x) dx =0$$ But $ sin(x) \neq cos(x) $ in general.

The tricky part here is $\phi$ might be less than $\psi$ in some places and greater in other places so that the integrals coincide. You need to show that this isn't the case. To do this, use the fact that $\psi(x)\geq \phi(x)$ by construction.

Gio67 shows a solution for this. You could directly work with $A_n=\{x:\psi(x)-\phi(x)\geq \frac 1 n\}$; this sequence of sets all need to be zero measure because of the theorem. This is really a method of contradiction; suppose $A_n$ has non-zero measure for any $n$. Then, $\int_A (\phi(x) -\psi(x)) dx \geq$  $\frac 1 n $ times the measure($A$). This contradicts that the integral of difference should be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Assume first that $f\ge 0$. Since $f$ is integrable you have that  $\int_{A_1\times A_2} f(x,y) \ dxdy <\infty$. In turn, applying your theorem you get $$0=\int_{A_1}dx
 \left(\overline{\int_{A_2}}f(x,y)\ dy\right)-\int_{A_1}dx
 \left(\underline{\int_{A_2}}f(x,y)\ dy\right) \\=\int_{A_1}dx
 \left(\overline{\int_{A_2}}f(x,y)\ dy-\underline{\int_{A_2}}f(x,y)\ dy\right).
$$
Since the upper integral is greater than the lower integral you have that the function 
$$g(x)=\overline{\int_{A_2}}f(x,y)\ dy-\underline{\int_{A_2}}f(x,y)\ dy$$ is integrable, nonnegative and has integral zero. But this implies that $g(x)=0$ for a.e. $x\in A_1$ (to see this, for every $n$ take the set $A_n=\{x\in A_1: g(x)>1/n\}$). This shows what you want for $f\ge 0$. The general case follows by applying this to the positive and negative part of $f$.